# Symfony 2.5 & twig: how to clean up this code?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, yaml

I'm new to Symfony and would like to use best-practices as early as possible. My code below works but it feels kinda dirty.

I worry, if I write too much code here. Maybe I miss some Symfony-background-magic that I don't know yet. Details below.

What would you change (why)? I appreciate every advice to become a better developer. Thanks in advance!

**routing.yml**:

```
items_edit:
  path:     /items/edit/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: myBundle:items:edit, id: null } # null = if not set?
  requirements:
    id: \d+
```

**ItemController.php**:

Do I have to pass the `$item` or is the data anyhow else gettable via twig?

```
public function editAction($id, Request $request) {
    $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('ItemsRepo');
    $item = $repo->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemFormType(), $item);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'saved.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('items_list'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'item' => $item // !!!
    ));
}
```

**edit.html.twig**:

Do I have to add `{id: item.id}` here?

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ path('items_edit', {id: item.id}) }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {# ... custom stuff ... #}     
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mr.B. what is `parentId`?

Comment: @xurshid29 Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id: null` with `\d+` requirement in your route is useless, because of you're actually editing the existing entity, you better remove it; `$em->persist($item);` is also unnecessary, because of you've already persisted and flushed it on creation, this time you don't need to persist again, just flush it. What abount passing the `$item` to form, if you want to show some information to the user, like "Editing the item with title of SOME_TITLE", or if there is some image field that you want to show thumbnail .., you can pass it and retreive field value, it's u to you.. Additional note, `/items/edit/{id}` is not very pretty, usually it's done like `/items/{id}/edit`, `/items/{id}/delete`...

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
<form action="{{ path('items_edit', {id: item.id}) }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

with

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
```

This way you do not need to pass `item` to the template.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template